# Excel data in Pandas raises a FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd

# Get stock data from excel
file_path = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\nifty1.csv")

#show the data
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

print(df.head())
```

Error I got for this code is

```
File "<ipython-input-59-276db8347c3f>", line 4
    file_path = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\nifty1.csv")
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Edited question to remove third-person references and comment about FileNotFound since that is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_path = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\nifty1.csv")
```

The string `"\U"` has special meaning in python.

Either change this to a raw string by putting an `r` in front:

```
r"C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\nifty1.csv"
```

Or use forward-slashes instead of backslashes:

```
"C:/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/nifty1.csv"
```

Comment: I have tried it didN't worked. please suggest me other solutions

Comment: @rajesh "it didn't work" gives me no idea of what actually went wrong.  Please edit your question to show the new code and the new error.

Comment: Also, my first example mistakenly had a `t` in front of the string, not an `r`.

Comment: i have tried wit r also. still it didn't executed

Comment: I have tried with all the solutions you have provided. I am getting same error

Comment: @rajesh That's not possible.  You must have made some other mistake.  Please update your question with the new code and the error.

Comment: @rajesh When you say "I am getting the same error", do you mean SyntaxError or FileNotFoundError?  Your question mentioned both of those...

Comment: file not found error

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape and also this error

Comment: @rajesh If you're still getting the syntax error, then you did **not** use my fixed code.  (Maybe you didn't save the code after editing it??)

Comment: @rajesh And again, you're saying both SyntaxError and FileNotFoundError.  It can only be **one** of those.  Which is it??

Comment: syntax error  File "<ipython-input-83-69a87f3660c9>", line 5
    df_excel = pd.read_xlsx("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\nifty1.xlsx")
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @rajesh That error does **not** have an `r` in front of the string.  So it looks like you did not use my suggestion...